# Сохранение обрезанного фото cropperjs

Tags: php, ajax

[image: Screenshot]   Всем привет,столкнулся с такой проблемой,нужно сохранить обрезанное фото на жесткий диск. В response почему-то приходит php код,который я прикреплю дальше,а так же скриншот,с PHP дело имею в первый раз...

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function ($) {
                $("input[name = 'img']").on("change",function () {
                    let image = document.getElementById('image');
                    let files = $(this)[0].files;
                    let file = files[0];
                    $('#image').attr('src',window.URL.createObjectURL(file));

                let cropper = new Cropper(image,{
                    aspectRatio:4/3,
                });

                    cropper.crop();

                $("button").on("click",function () {
                    cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob(function(blob) {
                        const formData = new FormData();

                        formData.append('croppedImage', blob);

                        // Use `jQuery.ajax` method
                        $.ajax('php/crop.php', {
                            method: "POST",
                            data: formData,
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            success(responce) {
                                console.log(responce);
                            },
                            error() {
                                console.log('Upload error');
                            },
                        });
                    });
                    })
                })
            })
        </script>


<?php
$fileName = $_FILES["croppedImage"]["name"];
echo $fileName;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["croppedImage"]["name"\],"saved/".$fileName."png");
echo json_encode($fileName);
?>][1]][1]
```

Comment: Такое ощущение что у вас сервер не сконфигурирован на выполнение php скриптов, но могу ошибаться..

Comment: похоже на то,а как его сконфигурировать? у меня Mac os

Comment: Не знаток конфигураций и сисадминства, и не знаю как с этим на маке, но обычно нужны такие программы как сам веб-сервер (например, apache) и php. Они как правило работают в связке (хотя не всегда). Если вы только тестируете у себя, для дальнейшего разворачивания на удаленном сервере, советую использовать готовые "сборки" типа XAMP, OpenServer и подобных (не знаю, какие из низ доступны на mac). Там обычно все уже сконфигурировано (сервер, php, mysql и прочее)

Comment: понял,спасибо :)